# Is there an example of two elementary particles colliding to result in a single elementary particle?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, collision, mass-energy, elementary-particles

Apologies for the novice question, but I don't know enough particle physics to immediately answer my own questions.

I have the following questions.

- Is there an example of an inelastic collision where two elementary particles "combine" to spawn a new elementary particle? ("Combine" is the wrong choice of words, because I'm interested in fundamental/elementary particles only.)
- If not, is there a reason why?

The reason for these questions is that I am curious if there is an example of a particle collision where mass is not conserved and the extra/missing mass cannot possibly be blamed on any internal energy modes.

An obvious example would be electron-positron annihilation $e^{+} + e^{-}\rightarrow \gamma + \gamma$, but that involves four particles in the entire process. Is there a less obvious example (preferably involving only three particles in total)?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there an example of an inelastic collision where two elementary particles "combine" to spawn a new elementary particle? ("Combine" is the wrong choice of words, because I'm interested in fundamental/elementary particles only.)

If you look at the [elementary particles table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) the Z is an elementary particle.

It is produced in e+e- scattering as [seen here:](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/hadronic-xsections/rpp2016-sigma_R_ee_plots.pdf) (it is now fig51.2), world data on the total crossection ...

[image: ee]

So in the strict mathematical sense and within the standard model of particle physics the answer to the title is YES. It is a resonance, its lifetime very short, but it is a basic elementary particle in the standard model.

The four vectors of the summed e+e- have the invariant mass of the Z, which decays in multiple ways.

The peaks with smaller mass are not considered elementary particle of the standard model, just resonances. The Z due to its large mass goes mostly to a large number of particles/hadrons , although Z to gamma gamma or mu+mu- exists ( the lower plot utilizes the mu+mu- crossection for the ratio with the hadronic crossection, if you read the link)

> an example of a particle collision where mass is not conserved

Mass is not a conserved quantity in elementary particle physics, because it obeys laws of special relativity. What is conserved is energy and momentum, considered a [single four vector.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) . The before and after interaction conservation of energy and momentum  ensures that the length of the summed four vectors have the same invariant  mass, before and after.